# Get value from selected optgroup and store it in Jquery variable

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is what i'm trying to achieve.  I have 3 optgroups selects , the 3 selects have the same tag name="DataEntered" i need to pass the selected option to a Jquery variable to submit that value without refreshing the form. Almost everything is working fine I'm just having 2 problems.

1- This Jquery function is taking the value only when one of the options in the the first select optgroup is selected, is not working on the remaining 2 selects, even if they have the same tag name

2- Once  the first selected value is passed i need to reset that selection, because in the second submit is still passing the value of the first option selected.

Jquery Function:

```
DataEntered:$('select[name=DataEntered]').val()
```

Html Selects:

```
<select  class="DropDown" Name="DataEntered">
<optgroup label="Customer Adjustment">
<option value="Agent called to make a Turn on/off">Turn on/off</option>
<option value="Agent called to make a credit Change">Credit Change</option>
<option value="Agent called to make a Temp Cred Change ">Temp Cred Change</option>
<option value="Agent called to Open New Customer">Open New Customer</option>
<option value="Agent called for other reason">Other</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="Product Question">
<option value="Agent called for Question1">Question1</option>
<option value="Agent called  for Question2">Question2</option>
<option value="Agent called for Question3">Question3</option>
<option value="Agent called for Question4">Question4</option>
<option value="Agent called for Other Question">Other</option>
</optgroup>
</select>


<select  class="DropDown"  Name="DataEntered">
<optgroup label="Account Adjustment">
<option value="Acc Adj-Change PW">Change PW</option>
<option value="Acc Adj-More Credit">More Credit</option>
<option value="Acc Adj-Turn off account">Turn off account</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="Product Question">
<option value="Agent called for Question1">Question1</option>
<option value="Agent called  for Question2">Question2</option>
<option value="Agent called for Question3">Question3</option>
<option value="Agent called for Question4">Question4</option>
<option value="Agent called for Other Question">Other</option>
</optgroup>
</select>


<select  class="DropDown"  Name="DataEntered">
<option value="Runner-Check item it">Check item it</option>
<option value="Runner-Check item it">Receive Work</option>
<option value="Runner-Check item it">Confirm/Ask for information</option>
<option value="Runner-Check item it">Problem</option>
<option value="Runner-Check item it">Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: DataEntered is now an array of 3 values because there are 3 elements with same name. You'll access each from DataEntered[0] and DataEntered[1] etc. Not a good thing though, I think.

Comment: It is a common misstake to use `.val()` on a select element. You have to figure out manually which element is selected, because the browser stores the selected elments into an array.

Answer (score 0):

You should use different names (DataEntered1, DataEntered2, DataEntered3) or select them by id example:

```
DataEntered:$('#dataenterd1').val()
<select id='dataenterd1' class="DropDown"  Name="DataEntered">
```

Comment: From the 3 selects only one is going to be chosen, how can i get that value in the  var DataEntered if i refer it by id. In other words how can i loop trough the 3 selects and see if is selected?

Answer (score 0):

By giving the same name DataEntered has become an array now. You can access value of each select like this:

```
DataEntered:$('select[name=DataEntered]');
Selected1: $(DataEntered[0]).val();
Selected2: $(DataEntered[1]).val();
Selected3: $(DataEntered[2]).val();
```

It is, however, not a good design. You should give each SELECT its own name or class or ID.

Comment: Each select has their own Id how can i get it by id?

Comment: DataEntered1:$('#DataEntered1').val(); DataEntered2:$('#DataEntered2').val(); DataEntered3:$('#DataEntered3').val();

Comment: But at the end i will need to store the selected option just in  one varible wich is DataEntered, and since always only one of the 3 select  is going to be chosen there are gonna be 2 selects empty. how can i know which id is the selected one and stored in DataEntered?

Comment: How can you store one result while there are three select fields? User can select one value from each, resulting in 3 values. Unless you are hiding or preventing user from selecting multiple values. You can catch onchange event on each select and capture its value... this will store the last selected value from last changed drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Easier way and can work for as much select as you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSelectValues(){
        $('select[name="DataEntered"]').each(function(){
            console.log($(this).val()); // here you can manage the value however you want to
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: How can i implement this function to return the SelectedValue and pass it to the Varible DataEntered?

Comment: you could build a object and return it for example:

`var dataArray = new Array();`

instead of console.log you could use this:

`dataArray[$(this).index()] = $(this).val()`

And in the end of the function you can insert `return dataArray;`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('select').change(function () {
        var opt = $(this).find(':selected');
        var sel = opt.val();
        var og = opt.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
        alert(sel);
        alert(og);
        $(this).find(':selected').text(sel + '-' + og);
    });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300846/4231110